# "He doesn't like the movies he used to" or "used to do"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question about avoiding using the same verb twice in a certain sentence.

When you are talking about someone's change of taste in films, I think you can say

> He doesn't like the movies he **used to like**.

If you want to avoid saying "like" twice in the same sentence, which of the sentences below sounds natural?

> He doesn't like the movies he **used to**.
>
> He doesn't like the movies he **used to do**.

Comment: You *could* use "do" there, and it might be "more acceptable / less "awkward" to Americans in particular. But most native speakers (specifically, me as a Brit) would either just repeat "like" (which isn't as "awkward" as you probably think), or discard the verb completely and end on ***to***.

Comment: The same awkwardness would apply *regardless* of the specific verb being replaced by *...as he used to **do***. Perhaps because I'm a Brit, I really don't think much of constructions like *He doesn't **go** to the movies as often as he used to **do***. There's absolutely no reason to have *any* finite verb at the end there - but imho if you insist on doing this it's better to repeat the original verb rather that just throw in ***do*** regardless of what it refers back to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The omission of words from a sentence is known as [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Whether or not the final verb can be omitted depends on what you think the complete sentence should be:

> He doesn't like the movies he used to **like**.
> He doesn't like the movies he used to **do**.

In my opinion, the first sentence is the best complete sentence and, as **like** occurs in the second clause in exactly the same form as in the first, it can be omitted from the second clause.

If you think that the second sentence is better, you cannot ellipsize **do** because it is a proxy for **like** in the first clause. It does not exactly match anything in the first clause in either form or function.

If the original sentence were

> He doesn't do the things that he used to do

The **do** in the second clause can be omitted, because it exactly matches the **do** in the first clause.